# Keep lines inside docstrings within 79 character limit

Tags: python, unit-testing, docstring, doctest

I am writing some doctests in my module.

Relevant code

```
def foo():
    """
    Populates the database with 'VALUES'

    >>> import sqlite3
    >>> con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    >>> cur = con.cursor()
    >>> cur.execute('select * from users').fetchall()
    [('admin', 'Admin', 1, 'admin123'), \
    ('foo', 'bar', 2, 'foo123'), \
    ('john', 'doe', 3, 'john123')]
    >>> 

    """

    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", VALUES)
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
    except sqlite3.OperationalError as msg:
        return msg
```

**Problem that I am facing**

```
$ python -m doctest test_db.py
Failed example:
    cur.execute('select * from users').fetchall()
Expected:
    [('admin', 'Admin', 1, 'admin123'),     ('foo', 'bar', 2, 'foo123'),     ('john', 'doe', 3, 'john123')]
Got:
    [('admin', 'Admin', 1, 'admin123'), ('foo', 'bar', 2, 'foo123'), ('john', 'doe', 3, 'john123')]
**********************************************************************
```

**References**

I looked into these but couldn't find something relevant

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/
- [How Do I Keep Python Code Under 80 Chars Without Making It Ugly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841226/how-do-i-keep-python-code-under-80-chars-without-making-it-ugly)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the extra whitespace.

```
def foo():
    """
    Populates the database with 'VALUES'

    >>> import sqlite3
    >>> con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    >>> cur = con.cursor()
    >>> cur.execute('select * from users').fetchall()
    [('admin', 'Admin', 1, 'admin123'), \
('foo', 'bar', 2, 'foo123'), \
('john', 'doe', 3, 'john123')]
    >>> 

    """
```

Comment: The standard interpretation of docstrings is to ignore leading whitespace in this fashion.  I'm rather surprised that doctest doesn't do that.

Comment: Agreed but isn't there anything which looks pleasing to the eyes?

Comment: The problem is that OP is using the line continuation character in a string. Therefore, they aren't considered new lines and therefore aren't subjected to the whitespace ignorance rule.